# Flask - Python:after replacing the file in static folder,template fails to show recent file and displays the former image with same name

Tags: python, html, flask

Using

- Framework -- Flask
- Language -- html ,python

Steps:

1. passing the name of file to be generated from template
2. desired file name is generated using a backend server which is an image
3. generated image is copied/replaced in static folder
4. template shows the image on webpage
5. but if 2 images are generated of same name ,template doesn't show the recent image 
   here is the code snippet :

   ```
   template -   <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename=file) }}" style="float:center"  width="300" height="200" alt="image not found">
   ```

code that replaces the file static folder :

```
def copyFileAndFindUrl(path):
  IMAGE_DIR='img/gol/'
  STATIC_DIR='./static/'
  url_file = ""
  #get basename of path:-->45:67.jpg
  base_name = getBaseName(path)
  print "baseName:",base_name
  #base_name = 'temp.jpg'
  #concat -> "img/" + baseFileName 
  url_file = IMAGE_DIR + base_name #"img/56:67.jpg" 
  print "url file:",url_file
  #copy(path,concat);return error
  dest_file = STATIC_DIR + url_file
  print "destination file:",dest_file
  if  os.path.exists(dest_file):
       os.remove(dest_file)
       print "removed:",dest_file
       print "checking after re:",os.path.exists(dest_file)
  ret = copyToStatic (path,dest_file)
  if ret :
      url_file = ''
      return ret,url_file
  #return concated file to display in webform
  return ret,url_file
```

please  let me know ,why after replacing the files ,recent image is not shown!!!

Comment: Is the original image being cached by your browser?

Comment: press Ctrl+F5 to get rid of possible browser cache

Comment: True ,image being cached .